# Initializing a static map using static members

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, static

Trying to initialize a static map. From other questions I've gathered that it must be done outside of the header file, and in c++11 can be done with uniform initialization. But when I try to use another static member, I get problems:

foo.h:

```
#include <map>

class TestSuite {
    static constexpr int x = 3;
    static std::map<int, int> v; 
};
```

foo.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"

std::map<int, int> TestSuite::v = {{x, 5}};

int main() {
    TestSuite t;
}
```

Then I get the error

```
In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
foo.cpp:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `TestSuite::x'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: seems to work fine, what compiler do you use?

Comment: 5.2, must be a new feature in 6.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this problem with GCC 6.1.0. However, it can be reproduced any time you try to bind a reference to a `constexpr` variable you haven't defined, which is probably what your `std::map` constructor does :

```
struct Foo {
    static constexpr int i = 42;
};

int main() {
    auto const &p = Foo::i; // undefined reference to `Foo::i'
}
```

This is because binding the reference is an [ODR-use](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) of `i`, which requires a unique definition to exist at link-time.

There is a simple workaround that works in most such cases, and that is to apply a unary `+`:

```
struct Foo {
    static constexpr int i = 42;
};

int main() {
    auto const &p = +Foo::i; // OK!
}
```

Applying `+` does not ODR-use `i`, since only its value is needed, not its identity. Then the reference binds to the temporary returned by `+`, instead of `i`.

Answer (score 3):

You also need to define `TestSuite::x`. Put this in your cpp file:

```
const int TestSuite::x;
```

Comment: Does static initialization order fiasco come into play at all?

Comment: @NathanOliver if both are in the same TU, then order of initialization is well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution.

Change the `static` member variable to a `static` member function.

```
class TestSuite {
    static constexpr int getX() { return 3;}
    static std::map<int, int> v; 
};
```

and

```
std::map<int, int> TestSuite::v = {{getX(), 5}};
```